# Poetry package debugging in VS Code correct launch and settings json

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, python-poetry

I'm building a package using poetry and have created my package name and venv. Using `poetry new package-name`

From the command line i can run `poetry run package-name --flags` and it will run my cli.py and references to appropriate imports etc.

My cli.py has `from package-name import module`. Everything works.

However in VS Code i'm trying to get it to run ^^ this command from the debugger interface declaring the appropriate parameters in the launch and settings json.

I had thought it would be something like

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/package-name/cli.py",
            "args": [
                "removeuser",
                "--ini",
                "../../ini/test.ini"
            ],
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

but this doesn't work. Any ideas on what the proper configuration is?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you looked at the `cwd` parameter of the launch config

Comment: Hi, have you found any solution to this problem, since you posted it here ?

Comment: I haven't i'm afraid, i've started using vim spector but still can't get the appropriate config

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```json
{
    "name": "Python: Poetry CLI application",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "module": "poetry",
    "args": [
        "run",
        "package-name",
        "removeuser",
        "--ini",
        "../../ini/test.ini"
    ],
    "console": "integratedTerminal"
}
```

I'm doing something similar and haven't found a better solution anywhere

Comment: It sadly just says: `/bin/python: No module named poetry
Running it with my module name instead says: `/bin/python: No module named mycli.__main__; 'mycli' is a package and cannot be directly executed`

Comment: Did you try `pip install poetry` in the environment you are debugging from?